# Elements inside ScrollView dont scroll React native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have trouble understanding how ScrollView works in React Native. In my view, I have a scrollview that is wrapped in a containerview with containerStyle that has a flex:1. However the elements inside my view dont scroll..

render() {
    const {containerStyle, eventsWrapperStyle, footerStyle} = styles
    return (

```
  <View style={containerStyle}>
    <Header/>
    <ScrollView style={eventsWrapperStyle}>
      {this.renderEvents()}
      {this.renderMonthlyStats()}
    </ScrollView>
    <Footer>
      <View style={styles.footerButtonsWrapper}>
        <Button customStyle={styles.footerButtonStyle} onPress = {() => this.props.resetAppInfo()}>NEW</Button>
        <Button customStyle={styles.footerButtonStyle} onPress={() => this.props.logoutUser()}>SIGN OUT</Button>
      </View>
    </Footer>
  </View>
)
```

}

```
const styles = {
  monthlyStatsWrapper: {
    margin: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  monthlyStatsLine: {
    width: '85%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  footerButtonsWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  footerButtonStyle: {
    width: 170
  },
  eventsWrapperStyle: {
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    paddingBottom: 100,
  }
};
```

[image]
Could you help me understand how scrollView works and make my elements inside it scroll ?

Here's the code for the Footer element which is absolutely positioned (might be part of the problem ?)

```
class Footer extends Component {
  render(){
    const { footerStyle } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={[footerStyle, this.props.customStyle]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ View>
    );
  }
};

const styles = {
  footerStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    bottom: 0,
    height: 130,
    backgroundColor: '#FCFCFC'

  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: How many elements are in the scroll list? I'm assuming there are alot more than you can currently see?

Comment: @JRK not a lot more, maybe 3 or 4 more

Comment: If you take out the footer, do all the elements properly show within the view?

Comment: actually even without the footer it is not scrolling up to the end. I am posting the footer code up there and a screenshot without the footer